# Basic JavaScript image-carousel not working

Tags: javascript, image, carousel

I am taking this course on edX and in the homework they have us build a web page with images that carousel automatically via JavaScript. EdX provided all the steps in full detail so you'd think I could just copy and paste and be all right; unfortunately it wasn't.

```js
var slideInterval = 3500;

function getFigures() {
  return document.getElementById('carousel').getElementsByTagName('figure');
}

function moveForward() {
  var pointer;
  var figures = getFigures();
  for (var i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    if (figures[i].className == 'visible') {
      figures[i].className = '';
      pointer = i;
    }
  }
  if (++pointer == figures.length) {
    pointer = 0;
  }
  figures[pointer].className = 'visible';
  setTimeout(moveForward, slideInterval);
}

function startPlayback() {
  setTimeout(moveForward, slideInterval);
}
startPlayback();
```

```css
@media not print {
  body {
    color: #635959;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #242323;
    color: #EFEFEF;
  }
  h3,
  article h4 {
    color: #8C1018;
  }
  article a {
    color: #314052;
  }
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
}

main figure>figcaption {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-style: italic;
}

main figure>figcaption::before {
  content: "Pictured above";
  font-weight: bold;
}

article>time {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

@media not print {
  main>h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

header {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

main {
  padding: 5px 10px
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'News Cycle';
  src: url('../fonts/mod3_news_cycle.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: 'News Cycle'
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Contrail One';
  src: url('../fonts/mod3_contrail_one.ttf');
}

header {
  font-family: 'Contrail One'
}

article {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 6px #888888
}

@media print {
  header {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  article {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  header h2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

section#carousel>figure>img {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

section#carousel>figure.visible>img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section#carousel>figure>figcaption {
  display: none;
}

section#carousel>figure.visible>figcaption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="US-en">

<head>
  <title>Contoso News</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script rel="text/javascript" href="js/script.js" /></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Contoso News</h1>
    <h2>On Time, On Topic</h2>
  </header>
  <section id="carousel">
    <figure class="visible">
      <img src="img/efficient_cars.png" alt="Efficient Cars" />
      <figcaption>2017 Cars Promise to be More Fuel Efficient Than Ever</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="img/natural_disaster.png" alt="Natural Disaster" />
      <figcaption>Hurricane Threatens to Touch Down on the East Coast This Weekend</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="img/health_records.png" alt="Health Records" />
      <figcaption>Many Doctors are Moving to Digital Health Records This Year</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <main>
    <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
    <article>
      <time datetime="16-01-2016">Friday, Jan 16</time>
      <h4>International Story</h4>
      <p> Curabitur pharetra luctus augue, non posuere orci tristique vel. Sed posuere nisi nec lacus ullamcorper, ac vulputate nisl consequat. Nullam sollicitudin nulla vel felis faucibus aliquam. Nunc sit amet velit orci. Proin sed orci fringilla, elementum
        felis condimentum, convallis augue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris tempus nunc sit amet aliquet bibendum. Praesent vestibulum cursus ex, quis laoreet eros consectetur ac. Ut congue libero quis mauris egestas feugiat. Sed pharetra lorem et magna
        fringilla, a volutpat nibh sollicitudin. Nullam sagittis sollicitudin urna, sed sollicitudin mauris ornare id. <a href="#" Target="_blank">Read More...</a>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <time datetime="16-14-2016">Wednesday,Jan 14</time>
      <h4>Finance Story</h4>
      <p>
        Nullam tempor mi at libero elementum varius. Sed lobortis lacus feugiat est tristique, nec imperdiet turpis scelerisque. Ut sed urna malesuada, scelerisque dui sit amet, tempus mauris. Integer bibendum egestas urna, a bibendum sem gravida quis. Cras accumsan
        rhoncus vestibulum. Nam eu blandit leo. Integer at consectetur nunc, et tempus urna. Integer sit amet sollicitudin elit. Donec nec posuere erat. Sed vestibulum nisl neque, vitae tincidunt ex molestie quis. Nulla fringilla viverra turpis in volutpat.
        Cras vel orci quis velit efficitur ullamcorper sed eu ex.
      </p>
      <figure>
        <img src="img/chip_debit.png" alt="Debit Card with Chip" />
        <figcaption>New Debit Cards with Chip-Based Security</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p>
        Nullam vel ex nec lectus imperdiet luctus vitae vel nibh. Donec eleifend velit eros, eu efficitur justo molestie id. In egestas gravida lectus. Ut ipsum odio, suscipit sit amet molestie non, scelerisque sed mi. Aenean sed augue eu arcu faucibus molestie.
        Sed eget ante gravida, rhoncus velit eu, tempus quam. Sed fermentum at odio sed commodo. Fusce lobortis cursus purus, quis consequat est faucibus at. Etiam massa felis, sodales at sodales sed, iaculis quis arcu. <a href="#" target="_blank">Read More...</a>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <time datetime="16-14-2016">Wednesday, Jan 14</time>
      <h4>Technology Story</h4>
      <p>Morbi eget justo ut velit dapibus malesuada. Nunc elementum, neque quis convallis tempus, lacus ante tristique est, id porta tortor leo eget orci. Suspendisse hendrerit interdum lacus et condimentum. Mauris at ex dignissim, bibendum libero at, fermentum
        lectus. Maecenas porttitor purus quis augue interdum, eget malesuada neque placerat. Ut hendrerit risus in nibh elementum, quis vestibulum ipsum vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In consectetur et lacus vel tincidunt. Quisque feugiat ipsum et erat rhoncus
        efficitur. In in augue at enim tempor sollicitudin. <a href="#" Target="_blank">Read More...</a>
      </p>
    </article>
  </main>
  <h4>Sign Up For Our Emails</h4>
  <summary>
    <form>
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" />
      <label>Delivery Preferences: </label>
      <select>
                        <option>Daily</option>
                        <option>Weekly</option>
                        <option>Monthly</option>
                    </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign-Up" />
    </form>
  </summary>
</body>

</html>
```

I've been combing through this code for this lesson for a few days now with no luck. I have everything as they do in the steps so any help would be AMAZING :D

Comment: What errors/unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: hey guys. so I'm super new to all this stuff, but when I go to the console I'm not seeing any errors. And when I load the page the image and caption loads but it does not pass on the visible class to the other images so it stays on the first image

Answer (score 0):

You have to define these two classes:

```
.visible {
  display: block;
}
.notVisible {
  display: none;
}
```

EDIT: The OP edited the question and changed the CSS, now my answer does not fit anymore.

And change your for loop to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    if (figures[i].className == 'visible') {
        figures[i].className = 'notVisible';
        pointer = i;
    }
}
```

```js
  var slideInterval = 3500;
function getFigures() {
    return document.getElementById('carousel').getElementsByTagName('figure');
}
function moveForward() {
    var pointer;
    var figures = getFigures();
    for (var i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
        if (figures[i].className == 'visible') {
            figures[i].className = 'notVisible';
            pointer = i;
        }
    }
    if (++pointer == figures.length) {
        pointer = 0;
    }
    figures[pointer].className = 'visible';
    setTimeout(moveForward, slideInterval);
}
function startPlayback() {    
    setTimeout(moveForward, slideInterval);
}
startPlayback();
```

```css
@media not print {
  body {
    color: #635959;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #242323;
    color: #EFEFEF;
  }
  h3,
  article h4 {
    color: #8C1018;
  }
  article a {
    color: #314052;
  }
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
}

main figure>figcaption {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-style: italic;
}

main figure>figcaption::before {
  content: "Pictured above";
  font-weight: bold;
}

article>time {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

@media not print {
  main>h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

header {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

main {
  padding: 5px 10px
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'News Cycle';
  src: url('../fonts/mod3_news_cycle.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: 'News Cycle'
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Contrail One';
  src: url('../fonts/mod3_contrail_one.ttf');
}

header {
  font-family: 'Contrail One'
}

article {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 6px #888888
}

@media print {
  header {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  article {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  header h2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

section#carousel>figure>img {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

section#carousel>figure.visible>img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section#carousel>figure>figcaption {
  display: none;
}

section#carousel>figure.visible>figcaption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
       <body>
            <header>
            <h1>Contoso News</h1>
            <h2>On Time, On Topic</h2>
            </header>
            <section id="carousel">
                    <figure class="visible">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Natural Disaster" />
                        <figcaption>Hurricane Threatens to Touch Down on the East Coast This Weekend</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="Health Records" />
                        <figcaption>Many Doctors are Moving to Digital Health Records This Year</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </section>
            <main>
                <h3>Latest Articles</h3>
                <article>
                    <time datetime="16-01-2016">Friday, Jan 16</time>
                    <h4>International Story</h4>
                    <p> Curabitur pharetra luctus augue, non posuere orci tristique vel. Sed posuere nisi nec lacus ullamcorper, ac vulputate nisl consequat. Nullam sollicitudin nulla vel felis faucibus aliquam. Nunc sit amet velit orci. Proin sed orci fringilla, elementum felis condimentum, convallis augue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris tempus nunc sit amet aliquet bibendum. Praesent vestibulum cursus ex, quis laoreet eros consectetur ac. Ut congue libero quis mauris egestas feugiat. Sed pharetra lorem et magna fringilla, a volutpat nibh sollicitudin. Nullam sagittis sollicitudin urna, sed sollicitudin mauris ornare id. <a href="#" Target="_blank">Read More...</a>
                     </p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <time datetime="16-14-2016">Wednesday,Jan 14</time>
                        <h4>Finance Story</h4>
                        <p> 
                            Nullam tempor mi at libero elementum varius. Sed lobortis lacus feugiat est tristique, nec imperdiet turpis scelerisque. Ut sed urna malesuada, scelerisque dui sit amet, tempus mauris. Integer bibendum egestas urna, a bibendum sem gravida quis. Cras accumsan rhoncus vestibulum. Nam eu blandit leo. Integer at consectetur nunc, et tempus urna. Integer sit amet sollicitudin elit. Donec nec posuere erat. Sed vestibulum nisl neque, vitae tincidunt ex molestie quis. Nulla fringilla viverra turpis in volutpat. Cras vel orci quis velit efficitur ullamcorper sed eu ex.
                        </p>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Debit Card with Chip" />
                            <figcaption>New Debit Cards with Chip-Based Security</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <p> 
                            Nullam vel ex nec lectus imperdiet luctus vitae vel nibh. Donec eleifend velit eros, eu efficitur justo molestie id. In egestas gravida lectus. Ut ipsum odio, suscipit sit amet molestie non, scelerisque sed mi. Aenean sed augue eu arcu faucibus molestie. Sed eget ante gravida, rhoncus velit eu, tempus quam. Sed fermentum at odio sed commodo. Fusce lobortis cursus purus, quis consequat est faucibus at. Etiam massa felis, sodales at sodales sed, iaculis quis arcu. <a href="#" target="_blank">Read More...</a>
                        </p>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <time datetime="16-14-2016">Wednesday, Jan 14</time>
                            <h4>Technology Story</h4>
                            <p>Morbi eget justo ut velit dapibus malesuada. Nunc elementum, neque quis convallis tempus, lacus ante tristique est, id porta tortor leo eget orci. Suspendisse hendrerit interdum lacus et condimentum. Mauris at ex dignissim, bibendum libero at, fermentum lectus. Maecenas porttitor purus quis augue interdum, eget malesuada neque placerat. Ut hendrerit risus in nibh elementum, quis vestibulum ipsum vulputate. Nulla facilisi. In consectetur et lacus vel tincidunt. Quisque feugiat ipsum et erat rhoncus efficitur. In in augue at enim tempor sollicitudin. <a href="#" Target="_blank">Read More...</a>
                            </p>
                        </article>
            </main>
            <h4>Sign Up For Our Emails</h4>
            <summary>
                <form>
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" />
                    <label>Delivery Preferences: </label>
                    <select>
                        <option>Daily</option>
                        <option>Weekly</option>
                        <option>Monthly</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign-Up" />
                </form>
            </summary>
        </body>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgnbkrrw/)

Answer (score 0):

problem was in the link to the javaScript. i wrote 'rel' like i was referencing a css stylesheet